# How to find which maven dependencies are missing

Tags: java, maven

I have a web project and a `pom.xml` file. It has enough dependencies to `compile` and `package` but not enough to start the project. In my IDE it's shown that everything is ok, but when a start the application it has errors. When i add external pom.xml from another app, my application launches.

So is there any way i can find out which dependencies are missing and how in future i can determine which dependencies are needed for using this or that?

Comment: what errors does it have?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `mvn dependency:analyze` for determining which dependencies  are `used and declared` or `used and undeclared` or `unused and declared`.
For more information refer to: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly reliable as at run time you'll find out you really need them!

Answer (score 4):

There's no maven command to accomplish this. You need to check which classes are causing `NoClassDefFoundError`, figure out the dependency (Google) - which JARs they are shipped in, and add them with the `runtime` scope in your pom.xml.

In web projects specifically you oftentimes compile against servlets or Java EE specification JARs (they would only contain interfaces), but you need actual implementation JARs to be present in runtime. These JARs are typically and presumed to be available in the container you are running in (like Tomcat or JBoss), in this case they would be marked as `provided` scope in your pom.xml.

Comment: You can use this website (http://www.findjar.com) to localize JARs by class names. Then you can find the maven dependence in http://search.maven.org/

Comment: You can also use search.maven.org or jarvana.com or mvnrepository.com.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `NoClassDefFoundError` in your output logs and add dependencies accordingly.

The best resource to search for missing dependencies is [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse)

To get a detailed debug log of your build, use `-X` in the command line.

You can check The dependency tree of your project by following command - `mvn dependency:tree`. This will only list the information about the deoendencies listed in your `pom.xml` More on it [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

should be able to do it with :

maven dependency resolve

[image]