# How these hibernate dependencies are conflicting?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat7

I have a `spring-mvc` maven-based project running on Tomcat7. Using `mvn dependency:tree` I got this:

[image]

When I don't have the dependency with the red arrow, my project runs just fine. When I add it, even if I don't use any classes from it, I have the following stack error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in conf.JPAConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:545)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:282)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:88)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:461)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(ConfigurationImpl.java:637)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:179)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:355)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:463)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:132)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
... 51 more
```

I looked [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841464/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-el-elmanager) and saw that I need `javax.el-api` dependency. If this is true, why `dependency:tree` doesn't show this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hibernate-validator` added on pom I have this error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
```

And below the cause of this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
```

Apparently, Tomcat7 have some 2.2 version of `el-api.jar` when I needed some new version. With Tomcat9 everything worked normally, as stated at the bottom of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45841464/3026886)

Answer (score 0):

By default at least, dependency:tree doesn't show dependency of scope "provided", system and perhaps not the "optional" ones either. You can try to use `dependency:analyze` as suggested by Farzad in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19005627/4660500).

Comment: Look again. The second and third root dependencies are provided. After `spring-mvc` we have `tomcat-servlet-api` and `jsp-api`, both provided. Analyze show used/unused. The dependency with red arrow is unused, as stated on question: "even if I don't use any classes from it". I thought about screenshotting `dependency: analyze` but since `dependency:tree` doesn't show any relation, I didn't think it mattered

Comment: @GabrielRado You are right, I was partially wrong; maven does show direct provided dependencies, but it seems it stops the analysis there. If you look at jsp-api for example, the [maven-central website](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api/2.3.2-b02) shows it has an el-api provided dependency not shown in your graph.